# Custom Login for FW and TW

Tags: ios, facebook, sharekit

I've searching on the FB iOS SDK and ShareKit, and seems that is not possible to have your own custom login screen. I'm correct?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are, unfortunately. They use OAuth and user must enter credentials into their webpage, or into iPhone's settings.